# reference counted class and multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, reference-counting

I 'm a novice in multithreading programing and i have still confusion with that.

Below is my reference counted class:

```
class Rbuffer
{
  private:
    char *m_pnData;
    volatile unsigned int mRefCount;

  public:
     Rbuffer(int nLength) : mRefCount(0)
    {
    m_pnData = new char[nLength]; 
    }
   ~Rbuffer(){
    delete[] m_pnData;
    }

   void decRef() {
     if(InterlockedDecrement(&mRefCount)==0){
               delete (Rbuffer *)this;
           }
    }

  void incRef() {
        InterlockedIncrement(&mRefCount);
    } 

};
```

is it fully thread safe? Can you exclude this situation:

```
ThreadA                                 ThreadB
PointerToRBuffer->incRef();//mRefCount 1
switch->  
                                        PointerToRBuffer->incRef();//mRefCount 2
                                          <-switch
PointerToRBuffer->decRef();           
InterlockedDecrement(&mRefCount)//mRefCount 1 
switch->                                
                                        PointerToRBuffer->decRef();//mRefCount 0!
                                        InterlockedDecrement(&mRefCount);
                                        if (0==0)
                                        delete (Rbuffer *)this; 
                                            <-switch
if (0==0) 
//deleting object, that doesn't exist 
delete (Rbuffer *)this;
//CRASH
```

The reasons of crashing could be that only **(InterlockedDecrement(&mRefCount))** part is atomic, but  **if (InterlockedDecrement(&mRefCount)==0)** not?
Am i wrong with example above?

Thanks in advance for your opinions and advice to make my class fully thread safe.

Comment: You're deleting a non-dynamic member variable (`delete[] m_pnData`) and making no affordances for protecting construction of a class who's instances can literally self-destruct (i.e. a static class factory method with a private constructor family). That said, I think your crash may have nothing to do with reference counting. Frankly, the fixed-casts on the `delete` operands should be equally concerning. I assume there is some reason you're not using `std::shared_ptr<Rbuffer>` for this, as that would make *all* of this irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your analysis isn't right; The code you posted is using `interlockedDecrement` correctly.

This is a safe use

```
 if(InterlockedDecrement(&mRefCount)==0)
           cleanup();
```

.. but this would indeed have the problem you described

```
 InterlockedDecrement(&mRefCount);

 if (mRefCount==0)
           cleanup();
```

However, the use of `delete this` is much more likely to be the cause of the problem. It's very unlikely you're passing the 'absolutely positively 100% sure' tests described here: 
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/delete-this.html

In particular, the following simple code would cause chaos.

```
{
  RBuffer x;  // count is what... ? zero
  x.incRef(); // make count one
  x.decRef(); // make count zero, and deletes itself 
}  // now x goes out of scope, so destructor is called a second time = chaos!
```

A normal "reference counting" idiom involves a 'shared object' (with the count), and simple 'reference objects' (not C++ references, although the semantics would be similar) which refer to the shared object. The constructors and destructors of the 'reference objects' are responsible for calling the `incref/decref` methods on the shared object. So the shared object is automatically counting the number of active 'reference objects'.

Comment: The member access of `mRefCount` is equally problematic in the first example. If `cleanup()` deletes the instance it also deletes the `mRefCount` being addressable (as it no longer exists), and as such a context switch to Thread B entering into the aforementioned if-expression eval switch after Thread A performs `delete this;` buried inside of `cleanup()` will still fault. If this is the problem you speak of in your description, I concur.

Comment: @WhozCraig is correct which is why I proposed a mutex around the whole decRef operation, and setting the PointerToRBuffer to NULL and adding NULL checks prior to derefencing PointerToRBuffer.

Comment: @WhozCraig if B hasn't completed the `interlockedDecrement`, then A won't delete the object, B would. So it's not an issue unless A tries to do `AddRef` again for some reason!

Comment: @ChrisDesjardins *exactly*. It *will* dereference an invalid address if A has deleted the object before B can invoke the interlocked-dec..

Comment: @ChrisDesjardins Where's the dereference?  (And wrapping it in a mutex likely won't help, because you'd be deleting the mutex in `delete this;`. My point is that you should only get to `cleanup` if there are no other references still live. If something does `decref` then tries accessing the object, you're toast.

Comment: @WhozCraig. If B calls `decref` after a has *completed* deleting the object, how does a mutex help you? The object doesn't exist, so B will crash? The mutex looks nice, but is a red herring here. It does *NOT* solve anything.

Comment: @Roddy "Where's the dereference?" What do you think `InterlockedDecrement(&mRefCount)` is doing? Its sending `&this->mRefCount` to `InterlockedDecrement`. Now consider if it is possible that `this` is no longer valid when that is done (and it *is* possible).

Comment: @WhozCraig I think you're missing the point that this is meant to be for reference counting: If something calls *any* method on the object after it's been deleted, then it's bad, even if single-threaded.

Comment: @Roddy I'm not missing anything, and I've had to implement reference-counted systems in the past. The only way to do this right is to protect the *pointers* which by their very nature are the references being counted, and is precisely what `std::shared_ptr<>` does. Doing this with naked pointers is a recipe for madness.  Nor did I say this may invoke a method on a deleted object. I said the object may be deleted *while the method call is in-process*, and as such, even `if(InterlockedDecrement(&mRefCount)==0)` is no silver bullet.

Comment: @WhozCraig thx you all guys for hot discussion,which indicates that i should use smart pointers, but by now can i simply surround all interrior of incRef, decRef method with entercriticalsection,leavecriticalsection?

Comment: @maciekm. Why not try it ? I can't see it making any difference. I think  any crash you're seeing will be in how you're USING this class, not in this class itself. Show some of the calling code...

Comment: @Roddy In this Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597582/iocp-multithreaded-server-and-reference-counted-class there is calling code. Note that  reference counted class in that question differs a litle from class in this question. But all refers to the same subject

Comment: @mackiem Understood: You do 4 grabs, and 4 releases. If the sequence is GGGGRRRR it 'frees' on the last release. If the sequence is GRGRGRGR what would happen? I *think* your use case is safe as you do all the 'G's in a critical section. If you're gettng crashes, temporarily comment out the `delete this` and see if they go away. Oh, and this might help. It describes how shared_ptr is implemented by MS. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982026.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It is not 100% clear what is going on, but it looks like ThreadA deletes the RBuffer object, and then subsequently ThreadB dereferences it.

What you really need is mutual exclusion around decrement and the delete operation, furthermore you need to set some kind of flag to prevent dereference after delete. Usually setting pointers to NULL works and then checking for NULL before any dereference.

So your decRef might look something like this:

```
 void decRef() {
     lock(_mutex);
     if(InterlockedDecrement(&mRefCount)==0) {
               PointerToRBuffer = NULL;
               delete (Rbuffer *)this;
           }
    }
```

You might be better off using a shared_ptr.

Comment: Why (and how) does `decref` (a class method) need to modify`PointerToRBuffer` (a pointer to an instance of that class)?

Comment: @Roddy I know this whole thing is ulgy, which is why a shared_ptr should be considered.

Comment: No doubt that Shared_ptr is the right solution! but learning how you might implement `shared_ptr` is an excellent skill to learn.