# reference counting with shared objects and reference object

Tags: c++, reference-counting

Based  on this description of reference counting below:

> "A normal "reference counting" idiom involves a '**shared object**' (with
>   the count), and simple '**reference objects**' (not C++ references,
>   although the semantics would be similar) which refer to the shared
>   object. The constructors and destructors of the 'reference objects'
>   are responsible for calling the incref/decref methods on the shared
>   object. So the shared object is automatically counting the number of
>   active 'reference objects."([reference counted class and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119061/reference-counted-class-and-multithreading))

i have search internet and found this example:

```
namespace Optimized {
struct StringBuf {
    StringBuf();             // start off empty
   ~StringBuf();             // delete the buffer
    void Reserve( size_t n );// ensure len >= n

    char*    buf;            // allocated buffer
    size_t   len;            // length of buffer
    size_t   used;           // # chars actually used
    unsigned refs;           // reference count
};

class String {
  public:
    String();                // start off empty
   ~String();                // decrement reference count
                             //  (delete buffer if refs==0)
    String( const String& ); // point at same buffer and
                             //  increment reference count
    void   Append( char );   // append one character
  private:
    StringBuf* data_;
 };
}

  namespace Optimized {

   StringBuf::StringBuf() : buf(0), len(0), used(0), refs(1) { }

   StringBuf::~StringBuf() { delete[] buf; }

   void StringBuf::Reserve( size_t n ) {
    if( len < n ) {
    size_t newlen = max( len * 1.5, n );
    char*  newbuf = new char[ newlen ];
    copy( buf, buf+used, newbuf );

    delete[] buf;   // now all the real work is
    buf = newbuf;   //  done, so take ownership
    len = newlen;
    }
  }

  String::String() : data_(new StringBuf) { }
  String::~String() {
  if( --data_->refs < 1 ) {
    delete data_;
      }
    }
   String::String( const String& other )
    : data_(other.data_)
    {
      ++data_->refs;
    }
 }
```

Is this example satisfies the conditions from description above? I mean, Does it involve **shared object**(is it StringBuf struct in that case?) and **reference objects**( String class)?

Comment: Kinda? The code as it is shown here plays at reference counting, but without any of the constructors that take part in reference counting (ie copy), hard to whether it counts properly. :-)

Comment: @Xarn i added copy constructor

Comment: Yeah, looks good, although completely thread unsafe.

Comment: @Xarn using InterlockedDecrement,Increment on refs is enough to make it thread-safe?

Comment: I will have to answer that one with a "no idea". I don't know `InterlockedIncrement`'s semantics and would prefer not to guess. (Also keep in mind that there are various definitions of thread-safe, and what needs to be synchronized depends on provided API to the string. For anything non-trivial you will also need some form of critical sections. (Think about realocations, accessing char at position via something like `[]` operator))

Comment: @Xarn can you refer to question "Does it involve shared object(is it StringBuf struct in that case?) and reference objects( String class)?"

Comment: Yes, it does satisfy the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is (almost*) never a good idea to mix business logic with life cycle management.

For this reason shared ownership with reference counting in `C++11 standard library` and well known `Boost library` is implemented in separate template classes encapsulating most commonly required ownership schemes.

In `Boost library` these are:

- `shared_ptr<T>` - shared ownership with reference counting (reference counter is allocated when the first instance of `shared_ptr<T>` for particular raw pointer `T*` is created).
- `weak_ptr<T>` - a handle that can be used to obtain full `shared_ptr<T>` if that one is still alive
- *`intrusive_ptr<T>` - shared ownership with reference counting where reference counter is a part of the object being managed. This particular class is an example of what you are trying to achieve, but already polished to industrial standard.

Comment: can you refer to this question "Does it involve shared object(is it StringBuf struct in that case?) and reference objects( String class)?"

Comment: your code does implement reference counting, but not at all the way it is thought of in `C++` context. In `shared_ptr<T>` the shared object will be hidden and owned by `template shared_ptr<class>` and reference object will be `T` and reference object won't know anything about reference counter what so ever.

Comment: Acorrding to description above in my question, we can treat Struct StringBuf as shared object and class String as reference object?