# Does delete resource need to be protected when using atomic reference counting?

Tags: c++, multithreading, reference-counting

In many cases, a resource can be shared by multiple threads. The resource handler could use atomic reference counting to handling those resources.

Suppose you have a resource handler such as `std::string a` in thread A.  Suppose this `std::string` uses an atomic reference counting mechanism internally.  Now suppose you make a shadow copy, like `std::string b=a`, where b is used in thread B.

I just read the question: [reference counted class and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119061/reference-counted-class-and-multithreading) and there are two answers there. The [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21119543/154911) said that the code snippet below is enough; note `cleanup` is called without any mutex protection:

```
if(InterlockedDecrement(&mRefCount)==0)
    cleanup();
```

But the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21119459/154911) wraps the `cleanup` function with a mutex:

```
void decRef() {
    lock(_mutex);
    if(InterlockedDecrement(&mRefCount)==0) {
        cleanup(); //mainly delete some resource
    }
}
```

My question here is, "Is the first answer correct?" How about this situation, when the instance `a` is destroyed in thread A:

```
if(InterlockedDecrement(&mRefCount)==0)
    // here, OS switch to another thread, and mRefCount is changed there
    cleanup();
```

...where the `mRefCount` may be concurrently changed in thread B (by `b`.)  After such a change in thread B, is it still safe to call `cleanup()` in thread A?

Comment: Nobody has a valid reference to the object anymore.  So of course you don't need a lock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried to look through that answer in a lot of detail, but I suspect you care about the problem in general more than just that particular question.

In a typical COW string<sup>1</sup>, when the reference count drops to 0, you no longer need to use a mutex (or anything similar) to protect cleanup.

The reason is fairly simple: at least in the usual case, you can only only create a new reference to the string by copying some existing reference to the string. When the reference count drops to zero, there *is* no longer any existing reference, so there's no source from which to create such a copy.

If you were working with something *other* than a COW string, you'd have to look at usage to figure out whether it was possible for a reference count to be incremented from a starting value of 0. For example, you could have some sort of cache holding recently used values, that used a reference count so as long as an object was referenced, it would stay in the cache. If no further reference to it existed, it would be *eligible* for removal from the cache. The next time you needed to add something to the cache, you'd find the oldest item with a reference count of 0, and replace it with the new item (and if there was no item with a reference count of 0, you'd either expand the cache or refuse to cache the new item, depending on cache policy).

In a case like that, it *would* be possible to find any item with a reference count of 0, then have a context switch that added a reference to that item, then switch back and (if you hadn't protected the cleanup with a mutex) delete the item even though it now has a non-zero reference count.

---

<sup>1. Although it's not particularly relevant here, a copy-on-write implementation of `std::string` is now specifically prohibited by the standard.</sup>

Comment: In the case of cache, it is better to go with `std::weak_ptr`.

Comment: Hi, Jerry, this is in-fact a COW string issue, not cache related. Thanks for the help.